# How do I store the last page visited on my Sitecore site and then display that when a user returns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore6

Quite new to Sitecore, I am building a Sitecore web application with no authentication (anonymous). It's a large project with lots of hierarchical top, side menus.

When the user revisits the website, I need load the page that was last visited with menu item highlighted. Could someone please help me whether there's any Sitecore API that provides this and if not what would be the ideal solution i.e. store last visited page on client cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option I can see would be storing the last visited page on client cookie like you said, then build in a custom processor and put it in the

```
<httpRequestBegin>
```

pipeline in the web.config.

A custom processor needs to inherit from the  HttpRequestProcessor class, and you'd need to override the Process method.

What I would suggest in this case is having your custom processor like this:

```
<processor type="Your.NameSpace.ClassName, Your.Assembly" />
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

and have something like the following:

```
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class ClassName : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            // Get cookie:
            var cookievalue = WebUtil.GetCookieValue("cookiename");
            WebUtil.Redirect(cookievalue);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this suggest you'll store the URL of the last visited page in the cookie. You could also store the ID of the last visited item in the cookie of course, and get it's path from there.

Comment: Thank you, how would you write to the cookie in first place? For each menu item click or any request processor?

Comment: You could do something with WebUtil.SetCookieValue("cookiename", "cookievalue"[, expirationdate]), perhaps calling that on pageload of every page (or put in place a different processor). 
The difficulty is to differentiate between current visit and next visit (you don't want people to be redirected to the old page when they are still in their visit).

Also, it might be worth looking into what Holger says, there might be something in OMS/DMS that can help you out doing this (differentiating between visits etc)

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this article, and as Holder mentions, it should be possible to get the information from DMS if you have it enabled and are using it:

[Get last visited pages from a Sitecore DMS (OMS) Profile](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/get-last-visited-pages-from-a-sitecore-dms-oms-profile/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't anything in the default API that does this.

There might be something in Sitecore OMS, but I don't know much about OMS.

I think a cookie, might be the easiest and simplest way of doing this.